# how to plot(scatter plot) the categorical data using Python seaborn library

Tags: python, seaborn, scatter-plot, categorical-data

I have 60+ categorical data point for X-axis. I used `seaborn.catplot`, it throws error like

> **"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"**

**Here my understanding is:** there is a problem with string and number concatenation and we cant use that much count of categorical data point on X-axis.

- is facet grid is good option to go?
- has anyone faced this issue earlier?
- any other python libraries available to plot a scatter plot with categorical variable?

Comment: You can use many different python plotting tools, including seaborn and matplotlib. The question does not make it clear where the problem lies.

Comment: Generally seaborn charts accepts numeric values as axis values. but in my case I need to print the string contents on x-axis. I am looking for the options like, integration of matplotlib chart and seaborn chart would help me to achieve my goal.

Comment: All the examples in the [catplot documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot) use strings. So if this is a conceptual question, please share at which point you do not understand the examples. If this is coding question, please share you code that produces the error (see [mcve]).

Comment: I need to plot this content on X- axis : 2018/01, 2018/02, 2018/03... 2018/12. I have a lot of date items, so I grouped it by month. this year/month is on object data type. while trying to plot it I got this error message : `ValueError: A wide-form input must have only numeric values.`